# Adicionando checkbox as linhas do datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Possuo uma aplicação em `WPF`, em que há uma janela com um `datagrid` com várias linhas, possuindo apenas registros. Nessa janela também há um botão e preciso que o usuário, ao clicar no botão, apareça em cada linha da `datagrid` um `checkbox`.

Depois do usuário ter finalizado a lista de checados, ele clicará novamente no botão que chamará uma função, percorrendo as linhas do `datagrid` e verificando quais estão checadas para fazer uma ação apenas nos registros checados.

Comment: Amigo foque a pergunta no problema que você quer a solução, parece que você está descrevendo uma funcionalidade que você quer que alguém implemente. Se possível coloque o treco de código também.

Comment: HStackOverflow eu sou um pouco novo em WPF mas sei c#, eu precisava mesmo de uma função para fazer isso.

Comment: Tentei fazer isso mas não funcionou:private void btnExcluir_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            

            for (var i = 0; i < dgPedidos.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                CheckBox ck = new CheckBox();
                dgPedidos.Items.Add(ck);
            }
        }

Comment: Dá esse erro: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

Comment: @jp_almeida Vê [isto](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15663211). Depois tens que adaptar ao teu caso: Precisas de adicionar [DataGridCheckBoxColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcheckboxcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) às Columns e não CheckBox aos Items como está num dos teus comentários.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar uma coluna com Template de um checkbox em cada linha em vez de apenas o nome, para isto a propriedade do seu objeto que estará sendo adicionada ao Datagrid deverá ser um booleano.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dtgUsuarios">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Habilitado">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding UsuarioHabilitado}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

         //Outras Colunas...
         //<DataGridTextColumn...            
         //<DataGridTextColumn...

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Adicione os usuários a Datagrid:

```
Usuario user = new Usuario();

dtgUsuarios.Items.Add(user);
```

E por ultimo com o clique do botão atualize os valores dos checkbox:

```
private void btAtualizar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in dtgUsuarios.Items)
    {
        bool novoValorCheckbox = item.UsuarioHabilitado;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> public class Pessoa  {  public int ID { get;
>   set; }  public string Nome{ get; set; } }
>
> public class PessoaModel : Pessoa {   public bool Selecionado { get;
>   set; } }
>
> private voids ButaoClick() { List lista = new
>   List(); lista = Carregadabasededados();
>   produtosDatagrid.ItemsSource = lista; }

Faz sentido

Comment: Eu usei:  <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <CheckBox></CheckBox>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header> dgPedidos.Columns[1].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            btnCancelar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; e deu certo.

Comment: No caso quando eu fiz do primeiro modo eu devo ativar a propriedade isreadonly="false" para checar, porém dessa maneira o usuário poderá editar os valores do grid.

Comment: jp_almeida, concordo plenamente, o modo que usou é o que mais se adequa ao que pretendia inicialmente. No meu exemplo não tive em consideração a questão do botao para mostrar as checkboxes, daí a minha resposta de facto não responder à sua questão. No entanto gostaria que percebesse a diferença, na sua versão está a adicionar checkboxes à datagrid que depois irá ter de analisar quais estão seleccionadas, no meu exemplo é o modelo de classes associado ao datagrid que automaticamente contem essa informação. Ambas as soluções  se adequam para incluir checkboxes no datagrid.

Comment: Rui Guerra, concordo contigo, mas eu criei também uma classe com todos os dados das linhas do grid e também um bool que controla se ta checado ou não. Para o controle da linha tenho o código. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Rui Guerra, tenho outro problema, eu tenho alguns botões nessa janela que fazem algumas coisas. Quando clico em qualquer um deles aparece os checks no datagrid e um botão de cancelar. Quando clico no cancelar, o mesmo some junto com os checks, mas quando clico novamente em algum botão ele da um erro: style specified element is already the logical child of another element. disconnect it first. Você poderia me ajudar? Obrigado.

Comment: private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dgPedidos.Columns[1].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;           
            btnCancelar.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;                       
        }